# Accessing data from mongodb from node js always returning timed out error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a website using react js as front end with node as back end and mongo db as database. I put some dummy data in the database like this[image: snapshot of mongo db]
and im using express and mongoose.created the database in atlas. the db connection is successful and all. but accessing the data within the collection by typing
'localhost:5000/companies' on the browser
companies returns  connection timed out error always.
my server.js file looks like this

```
const express=require('express')
const { connectDB,disconnectDB  } = require('./db');
const cors = require('cors');
const Company = require('./models/Company');


var app = express();




// Enable CORS for specific origins
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000' // Allow requests from http://localhost:3000
  }));
  

app.get("/api",(req,res)=>{
    res.json({"users":["user1","user2", "user3"]})
})

app.get("/Companies",async (request,response)=>{
    try {
        // Connect to MongoDB (if not already connected)
        await connectDB();

        // Fetch all companies from the companies collection
        const companies = await Company.find();
        
        // Send the list of companies as a JSON response
        response.json(companies);
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle errors
        console.error('Error fetching companies:', error);
        response.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
    
})

app.listen("5000",()=>{
    console.log("Server is running on port 5000")
});

// Handle graceful shutdown
process.on('SIGINT', async () => {
    try {
        await disconnectDB();
        console.log('Disconnected from MongoDB');
        process.exit(0);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error disconnecting from MongoDB:', error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

and my model Company looks like this

```
// models/Company.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Define the schema for the Company collection
const companySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    "_company_name": String,
    "_link": String
    // You can define other fields as needed
});

// Create a Mongoose model for the Company collection
const Company = mongoose.model('companies', companySchema);

module.exports = Company;
```

and my db.js is

```
  // db.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const connectDB = async () => {
   
   try {
       await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Zien', {
       });
       console.log('db connection success');
   } catch (error) {
       console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', error);
   }
};

const disconnectDB = async () => {
   try {
       await mongoose.disconnect();
       console.log('Disconnected from MongoDB');
   } catch (error) {
       console.error('Error disconnecting from MongoDB:', error);
   }
};

module.exports = { connectDB, disconnectDB };
```

i tried on a locally installed mongodb as provided in the code along with the atlas mongodb string. got same error as output

i tried to reduce the number of documents fetched in one call by changing
`const companies = await Company.find().limit(10);`
but still no response.but giving the limit(10) do return connection timed out error always.

and i tried to console it like
`const result = await Company.find().limit(10).explain(); console.log(result);`

and it consoled

> Error fetching companies: MongooseError: Operation `companies.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
> at Timeout. (D:\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:186:23)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)

and i tried to convert it to array. like
`await Company.find().limit(10).toArray()`

and it returned

> Error fetching companies: TypeError: Company.find(...).limit(...).toArray is not a function
> at D:\xampp\htdocs\employerrating\application\views\modules\zien-backend\server.js:33:56

help?

**EDIT and solution**
thank you guys. its works now . as @JQueeny pointed out to move my `connectDB` , i rewrote the

```
app.listen("5000",async ()=>{
        console.log("Server is running on port 5000")   
});
```

to

```
app.listen("5000",async ()=>{
    try {
        await connectDB();
        console.log("Server is running on port 5000")
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error starting server:", error);
    }
    
});
```

and it finally works. i think the problem was i was trying to connect to database every time i tried to access the companies documents.
Thank you

Comment: I don't think your nodejs application is connected to the DB, can you also provide your `db.js`?

Comment: `.toArray()` is a method of the Node.js native driver `find` method for MongoDB. It 
 doesn't exist on mongoose model methods. The `buffering timed out after 10000ms` is a generic error message that basically means you tried to query the data before a connection was established and now it's timed out. I suspect your problem is in your `db.js` file that @kennysliding has requested you share.

Comment: yes. sure. i have edited my question including my db.js @kennysliding

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Company.find({})
```

If you are getting timeout from your db and you are sure that there are not that many documents to fetch, it means that it is very likely that your request is not valid. It is possible that you are calling a method incorrectly or you are not returning something. from what you provided find({}) should solve your problem. If not, I'd suggest you to provide more details.

Comment: This not correct. OP has the correct syntax for making a query: `const companies = await Company.find();` The `Model.find` method defaults to an empty query object if one is not provided so `find()` and `find({})` result in the same query.

Comment: i tried it. got the same result

Comment: @amalu apart from finding all documents, were you able to fetch any data in your express app?

Comment: @DenizKaradağ none from the database so far.The `limit(10)`  was added because i thought the document count was too high. but it does not seems to be the issue

Answer (score 0):

As per the mongoose [Model docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html):

> The first argument is the **singular name of the collection your model is for**. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name.

Change this:

```js
const Company = mongoose.model('companies', companySchema);
```

to this:

```js
const Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);
```

Mongoose uses a library to convert your model name to the pluralised version of your model name and use that as the name of your collection.

Comment: changed to `const Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);`. But same  buffering timed out error

Comment: Does your `console.log('db connection success')` log to the console?

Comment: You are runng `connectDB()` inside every request. Move it to the top of the file straight after you import the module and before you import your Model.

Comment: Yes connection success does show in console log @jQueeny. I will try move  `connectDB()` and run again

Comment: Its seemed to have worked. i moved `connectDB` to my `app.listen` function.thank you so much. i have been trying for 3 days @jQueeny

Answer (score 0):

I always connect to mongoose via:

`const Company = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema, {{schemaName}});`

whereas {{schemaName}} = in your case would just be 'Company'